# Connect Excel to extern Oracle 19 database via VBA and ODBC

Tags: excel, vba, connection, oracle19c

First, sorry if my English is not that good; I am a trainee in software development and still learning English.

I made a virtual machine on vSphere with Oracle 19c and Windows Server 2016 64 bit and made an Excel file with macros on this machine. This Excel file is for our Customer to create invoices based on data from the Oracle database. Now our Customer should not perform on his server later when our software and database is delivered, instead he should do what he is doing on an external client which is maybe on the same network.

That is where the Problem starts, I copied the file on my laptop and changed the connection string the `"HOST=..."` part with the IP-Address from the VM. When I start the Sub a box appears with the message: `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The Datasourcename was not found, and no default driver specified.`

Thank you for your help.

```
Private Sub Cmd1_Click()
'Variablen deklaration
Dim dbConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim recordSet As ADODB.recordSet
Dim conString As String
Dim ipAddress As String
Dim port As String
Dim userId As String
Dim password As String
Dim driver As String
Dim dateFrom As String
Dim dateTo As String
Dim Query As String
Dim Lastrow1 As Long
Dim Lastrow2 As Long

'Vorhandene Daten löschen vor dem neuschreiben
Lastrow1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lagergeld").Range("B" & 
Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lagergeld").Range("B3:H" & Lastrow1).Clear

Lastrow2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dienstleistungen").Range("B" & 
Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dienstleistungen").Range("B3:H" & Lastrow2).Clear

Set dbConnection = New ADODB.Connection

' Variables are in a table in the same workbook
userId = Worksheets("Stammdaten").Range("Q4").Value 
password = Worksheets("Stammdaten").Range("Q5").Value 
ipAddress = Worksheets("Stammdaten").Range("Q6").Value '10.10.10.120
port = Worksheets("Stammdaten").Range("Q7").Value '1521 
driver = Worksheets("Stammdaten").Range("Q8").Value ' {Oracle in 
OraDB19Home1} tried several like {Microsoft ODBC for Oracle} and others

conString = "Driver=" & driver & ";" & _
            "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
            "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
            "(HOST=" & ipAddress & ")(Port=" & port & "))" & _
            "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=prod.world)));" & _
            "user id=" & userId & ";password=" & password & ";)"

dbConnection.Open (conString)

dateFrom = Worksheets("Auswahl").Range("B12").Value
dateTo = Worksheets("Auswahl").Range("C12").Value
dateFrom = dateFrom & " 00:00:00"
dateTo = dateTo & " 23:59:59"

'Lagergeld
', VasStfCarrierFamilyTypes vscft
Query = " SELECT TO_CHAR(vsf.CreationTime, 'DD.MM.YYYY'), vscf.Name, 
vscf.ReferenceHeight *" & _
        " vscfh.Factor, vsf.TaxAttribute1, vsf.TaxAttribute2, vsf.Quantity, 
vsf.TaxPoint " & _
        " FROM VasStorageFee vsf, VasStfCarrierFamily vscf, 
VasStfCarrierFamilyHeight vscfh" & _
        " WHERE 1 = 1 " & _
        " AND vsf.CreationTime >= TO_DATE('" & dateFrom & "', 'DD-MM-YYYY 
         HH24:MI:SS') " & _
        " AND vsf.CreationTime <= TO_DATE('" & dateTo & "', 'DD-MM-YYYY 
          HH24:MI:SS')" & _
        " AND vsf.OwnerCode = '" & Modul1.GetOwnerCode & "'" & _
        " AND vsf.CarrierFamily = vscf.ID " & _
        " AND vsf.EffectiveHeight = vscfh.ID " & _
        " ORDER BY vsf.CreationTime ASC"


Set recordSet = dbConnection.Execute(Query)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lagergeld").Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lagergeld").Range("B3").CopyFromRecordset recordSet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lagergeld").Range("B3").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"

recordSet.Close

'Dienstleistungen
Query2 = " SELECT TO_CHAR(vsf.CreationTime, 'DD.MM.YYYY'), va.Description, 
           vsf.CarrierCode," & _
         " vsf.MessageText, vsf.ArticleCode, vsf.Quantity,  vsf.Taxpoint " & 
           _
         " FROM VasServiceFee vsf, VasActivity va" & _
         " WHERE 1 = 1" & _
         " AND vsf.CreationTime >= TO_DATE('" & dateFrom & "', 'DD-MM-YYYY 
           HH24:MI:SS') " & _
         " AND vsf.CreationTime <= TO_DATE('" & dateTo & "', 'DD-MM-YYYY 
           HH24:MI:SS')" & _
         " AND vsf.OwnerCode = '" & Modul1.GetOwnerCode & "'" & _
         " AND vsf.Activity = va.ID " & _
         " ORDER BY vsf.CreationTime ASC"


Set recordSet = dbConnection.Execute(Query2)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dienstleistungen").Range("B3").CopyFromRecordset 
recordSet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dienstleistungen").Range("B3").NumberFormat = 
"dd.mm.yyyy"

recordSet.Close

dbConnection.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried installing several Drivers but no one seems to work.

Comment: You connection string at least has a mismatch in brackets

Comment: ohh you were right, I have corrected it but it still gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

solution was found, thanks to Eliton who made a comment on another issue. I have now installed the correct driver and adjusted the tnsnames.ora and the environment variables. With sqlplus and the ODBC - Manager from Microsoft I was able to connect successfully.
the only thing that was wrong was my connectionString
It has to be:

```
conString = "Driver={Oracle in instantclient_19_6}; DBQ=prod.world; PUID=myUser;" & _ 
            "Pwd=myPassword"
```